# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Texlive 2018 ! LaTeX Error: File `ulem.sty' not found

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu, r, texlive-2018

After installing [tinytex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tinytex/index.html) `R` package, I started getting `LaTeX` error regarding missing `.sty` files. One such error is

```
LaTeX Error: File `ulem.sty' not found.
```

I used the following code

Checked Texlive version

```
$ tex -v
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Where is Texlive installed

```
$ which latex
/home/myaseen/bin/latex
```

Where is Texlive installed

```
$ whereis latex
latex: /usr/bin/latex /home/myaseen/bin/latex /usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz
```

Locating `ulem.sty`

```
$ locate ulem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-ulem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/zhspacing/zhulem.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJKulem.sty
```

Making ulem directory

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ulem
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ulem’: File exists
```

Copying ulem.sty file

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ulem/
```

Running texhash

```
$ sudo texhash
```

Locating `ulem.sty`

```
$ locate ulem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-ulem.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/zhspacing/zhulem.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJKulem.sty
```

Wonder how to fix the problem?

Comment: Why is there a different copy of `latex` installed in your home directory from the one on your system? It might not be reading the same directories. If you really need to do this, you might install the package in usermode.

Comment: Thanks @Davislor for your comment. I was also worry about that but do not know how to fix it. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Presumably your `/home/myaseen/bin` directory is in your `PATH` before the system directories. You could remove it from your `PATH` and try again, or you might even temporarily rename it to something like `/home/myaseen/bin/latex.disable`.

Comment: If you don’t know why you have a copy there, it seems like you definitely should be running the one that gets updates.

Comment: Also, in general, you shouldn’t be copying TeX packages manually. Use your package manager to find out which package contains the file, e.g. `apt-file ulem.sty`. Then install that package. If you have a different TeX distribution than the `texlive` supplied by Ubuntu, use its installer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to install `texlive-plain-generic` to get `ulem.sty` working:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-plain-generic
```